# List is not getting returned properly from JUnit code while mocking HQL findAll

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit

i was trying to mock hql (findAll) and it is returning a list as below

```
      PatientVisit patientVisit=new          
      PatientVisit(id:10,visitDate:d,patient:patient,height:175,weight:65,velocity:19)      
      mockDomain(PatientVisit,[patientVisit])


      def mocker = mockFor(PatientVisit, true)
      mocker.demand.static.findAll(1) {  hqlString,params ->




        PatientVisit.findAll(){testJob ->

        List <PatientVisit> pl= []

        pl.add(PatientVisit)
        PatientVisit p=PatientVisit.get(10)
        pl.add(p)
        pl.add(p)
        //just added to increase the size of list

        println "returning :"+pl.size() //this gives 3

        return pl

      }
  }
```

This is being called from controller as below

```
 List<PatientVisit> patientVisitList = PatientVisit?.findAll("from PatientVisit as pv where   
 pv.patient.id = :patientID order by pv.visitDate asc", [patientID:pat.id]);
```

But its size is just 1.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: i tried to iterate through the list and when it calls it.next(), it stops execution...................................println patientVisitList.size()
Iterator it1=patientVisitList.iterator()

Answer (score 0):

Worked when i put return in the outer block.

Comment: Please add the updated code in this answer (don't edit the question, in order to keep the problem), it may help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def mocker = mockFor(PatientVisit, true)
  mocker.demand.static.findAll(1) {  hqlString,params ->




       PatientVisit.findAll(){testJob ->

           List <PatientVisit> pl= []

           pl.add(PatientVisit)
           PatientVisit p=PatientVisit.get(10)
           pl.add(p)
           pl.add(p)
           //just added to increase the size of list

           println "returning :"+pl.size() //this gives 3      

        }  
    return pl
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mocker = mockFor(PatientVisit, true)  mocker.demand.static.findAll(1) {  hqlString,params ->

   PatientVisit.findAll(){testJob ->

       List <PatientVisit> pl= []

       pl.add(PatientVisit)
       PatientVisit p=PatientVisit.get(10)
       pl.add(p)
       pl.add(p)
       //just added to increase the size of list

       println "returning :"+pl.size() //this gives 3      

     }  
   return pl
  }
```